# Добавление картинок в pydroid 3

Tags: python, pydroid

Всем привет столкнулся с проблемой добавления изображения на екран.
Есть код с помощью которого хочу открыть картинку с помощью PIL но из-за того что я работаю на андроид я не понимаю как прописать путь к месту где находится картинкa пробовал смотреть через файл менеджер и прочее также пробовал  load ввестo open

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a PIL Image
img=Image.open("storage/emulated/0/a.ipg") 

# Display with Matplotlib
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы указали относительный путь, надо абсолютный:

```
/storage/emulated/0/a.ipg
```

Вы забыли поставить в начале `/`

Comment: Спасибо а то я думал нужно прописывать дополнительно что-то вроде диска С

Comment: Кстати пока пробовал решить свою проблему нашёл возможно новый способ добавления изображения используя код```import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

ball = pygame.image.load("a.png")
ballrect = ball.get_rect()

surface.blit(ball, ballrect)
pygame.display.flip()```
Я переместил картинку а.png в /Android/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/bouncingball. В общества я переместил картинку в само приложение и теперь не нужно прописивать путь

Comment: @HerowarkArk Это и называется относительный путь.